# Gradle doesn't find my Android Annotations generated classes

Tags: android, gradle

I'm using gradle and intellij to build my android project. My generated java files are stored in the .aagen directory. I can import all these generated classes in my non generated classes. Still when I build my project with my build.gradle script this is the output.

```
/android/source/com/app/App.java:30: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class TestActivity_
location: package com.ui
import com.ui.TestActivity_;
```

This is my error I got:

```
aused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.jdk6.Jdk6JavaCompiler.execute(Jdk6JavaCompiler.java:42)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.jdk6.Jdk6JavaCompiler.execute(Jdk6JavaCompiler.java:33)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:95)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:48)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:34)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.DelegatingJavaCompiler.execute(DelegatingJavaCompiler.java:29)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.DelegatingJavaCompiler.execute(DelegatingJavaCompiler.java:20)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.execute(IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.java:33)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.execute(IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.java:24)
at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.Compile.compile(Compile.java:68)
at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:216)
at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:122)
at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.groovy:23)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:217)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:199)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:526)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:509)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
... 67 more
```

Comment: Can you post your project's build.gradle file? Your gradle build file is probably out of sync with your Android Studio project if it works in Android Studio but doesn't compile with gradle.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? If so, how?